# Unable to access COM exposed methods in VBA

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, vba, com

I am trying to access COM exposed methods in VBA.

**Problem:** I am seeing all default methods (like `GetHashCode`, `GetType` and `ToString`) in VBA but *not* the ones which are part of the COM interface and specifically written to be COM visible (like `getStringValue()` below).

Set up Details:

- Visual Studio 2008
- Windows 7 x64
- Office 2007
- .NET 3.5

### Interface 'IGetMyString.cs'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SimpleCOMAssembly
{
    [ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("4153A1AC-ECE9-4f66-B56C-1DDEB6514D5D")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    interface IGetMyString
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string getStringValue();
    }
}
```

### Implementation 'GetMyString.cs'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SimpleCOMAssembly
{
    [ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("0A3D4D65-CF50-4020-BF13-77001F8AAABE")]
    [ProgId("SimpleCOMAssembly.GetMyString")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class GetMyString : IGetMyString
    {
        public GetMyString() { }

        [ComVisible(true), Description("Get my string")]
        public string getStringValue()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

In Build properties, I checked **'Make Assembly COM Visible'** (see below snapshot)

[image]

Also asked Visual Studio 2005 to make the **'Register for COM interop'** (see below snapshot)

[image]

And, finally as a post build event, I am running the regasm.exe to register the .DLL and also the .TLB to registry as follows:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm /codebase "$(TargetPath)" /tlb:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).lib"
```

In Excel Object Explorer view, I enabled COM server (SimpleCOMAssembly written above), and now in the Object Explorer it does not list down the COM interface method (see below)
[image]

Can someone help me know what I am missing which is causing the COM interface methods not show in VBA?

**EDIT**
Attaching ITypeLib View of the generated TLB
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Excel object browser screenshot clearly shows a problem. Note how the GetHashcode, GetType and ToString methods are visible.  Those are methods that are inherited from System.Object.  But your snippet explicitly (and correctly) uses [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] so that the class implementation is hidden.

It isn't hidden.  Not so sure how that happened, an old type library from an earlier attempt could explain it.  But your build steps are very suspect, you are helping too much.  The "Make assembly types COM visible" option is a pretty crude way to force the build system to expose .NET types.  But your code is using the refined upper-right-pinky-up-when-you-drink-tea way to expose types to COM.  Which includes the [ComVisible(true)] attribute, what the checkbox does, and the [ClassInterface] attribute, which is what the checkbox doesn't do.

So the problem is that you asked the build system to implement *two* interfaces.  Whatever it inherited from the base class, _Object in your case, plus what it inherited from the declaration, IMyGetString in your case.  Which is fine and all quite COM compatible, but VBA isn't a very good COM consumer.  It only likes the [Default] interface and that's _Object in your case.  Clearly visible from the screenshot.

So turn off the "Make assembly COM visible" option.

And choose between either a postbuild event that calls Regasm or the "Register for COM interop" checkbox.  Doing it both ways just doubles the odds that you don't know why it doesn't work.  You only need the postbuild when you need to register the assembly for the 64-bit version of Office.

Comment: Hans, actually the code snippet and the screenshots are in-sync to the best of my understanding. Also I am already using the /tlb option in the post-build command. I will try other suggested fixes and come back on them shortly. Thanks!

Comment: I'd have to guess at the 2nd bullet, it might override the attribute.  Something I've never got wrong by accident myself so I don't know what it might do.  With the side effect that the interface isn't the default interface anymore.  Get a second opinion by running OleView.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Use File + View Typelib to look at the type library.  Check the coclass and look at the interface with the [Default] annotation.  It won't work if it isn't IMyGetString.  I'll fix my answer if you can confirm this.

Comment: Hans, I added a screenshot of the OLE View of the TLB above.

Comment: Hans, this is what I see in the OLE View     `coclass GetMyString {
        [default] interface _Object;
    };`

Comment: Oh, wait, the screenshot doesn't show the IMyGetString interface at all.  Not even as a non-[default] interface.  Back to my original explanation, out-dated type library.

Comment: @HansPassant may be you can shed some light on a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275357/net-registered-dll-does-not-show-function-in-vb6

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. I found this link.

[Guide to calling a .net library from excel](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/)
If I am referencing a TLB file called "Foo.tlb" which has a class called "FooClass" that has public members. You will not be able to see those members because they are built by default with late binding (run-time binding) interface only.

You can change your class to have early binding, which will allow for intellisense and the Members of the class to be exposed in the Object browser.

C#:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class FooClass
{
    public FooClass()
    {
    }
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "I am printing....";
    }
}
```

You should be able to see the DoSomething method in the object browser after you implement this change. Note: You will have to deference the dll first.

Answer (score 2):

For the record - in case anyone else needs this answer - I just had the exact same issue as this (OLEView and everything) and it was driving me nuts. I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong, because I've created several C# COMs before. I forgot to declare the interface (in this post that would be `IGetMyString`) as `public`.

Hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, for the sake of others who look at the current [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575040/10241377) there are a few other ways you can go about this in Visual Studio.

First I checked "Make Assembly COM visible" and "Register for COM interop" (under the build options).

Then going further I just added to my **PUBLIC** interface:

```
[Guid("[some guid]")]
```

and just went over to my **public** class and added this:

```
[Guid("[some other unique guid]")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
```

and that just works.  If you did everything correctly then you should have a dll and a tlb in your compilation.  From there import them into the project you are working on and VB6 will see and display all your objects' methods and any other exposed values/setters/getters, enums also seem to work fine using this method too.

Environment:

- Using the .NET Framework version 4.7.2
- Windows 10