# Using DLL in Access 2013 - how to make the calling/initializing of the DLL class easier

Tags: c#, .net, vba, dll

For a project I am trying to create a custom library which is created in C# and used in Access. To do this I did the following:

- created a class library in visual studio 2012,
- Made the assembly COM visible (in Project properties --> Assembly information),
- Registered the project for COM interop,
- Included `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` in my class.

The purpose of the DLL is to handle/send mails through SMTP with multiple addresses, attachments etc. To do this I created the following:

```
[Serializable(), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComVisible(true)]
public class SendOPSMail
{

    public void SendMail(string ToAddress, string Subject, string Body, string FromAddress, ref string[] attachments, string CCAddress = "", string BCCAddress = "")
    {

                //Check if attachment is null or not else assign empty value
                attachments = attachments ?? new string[0]; //after research it seems that I cant assign a NULL array in VBA/DLL and need to be passed by ref - so this can be deleted


                using (var msg = new MailMessage())
                using (var client = new SmtpClient("spamfilter.mySpamFilter.com", 587))
                {

                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true; 
                    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FromAddress))
                    {
                        msg.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
                    }

                    string[] splitTO = ToAddress.Split(delimiterChars);

                    foreach (var TO in splitTO)
                    {
                        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
                    }

                    //handle attachments
                    foreach (string value in bijlagen)
                    {
                        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(value));
                    }

                    //set the remaining required fields
                    msg.Body = Body;
                    msg.Subject = Subject;

                    //Send mail
                    client.Send(msg);

                }


    }
}
```

I included the DLL in my Access references and this went all good. Though when I try to call my class as follow:

```
Dim test As OPS2Mail.SendOPSMail
Set test = New OPS2Mail.SendOPSMail

test.SendMail "some@email.com", "Test", "<b>Test</b>", "some@email.com", AttachmentArray
```

I get the (Access/VBA) error `438, the property or method is not supported for this object.`

So after research I found a post where they stated I have to create a main class in the DLL which calls the class with the function (SendOPSMail) and then in VBA I initialize that Main class first to call the other class. So in the DLL code I added:

```
public class MainOPSMail
    {
        public SendOPSMail GetSendOPSMail()
        {
            return new SendOPSMail();
        }
    }
```

and in VBA/Access I changed it to:

```
Dim testMain As OPS2Mail.MainOPSMail
Set testMain = New OPS2Mail.MainOPSMail

Dim test as OPS2Mail.SendOPSMail
set test = testMain.GetSendOPSMail

test.SendMail "some@email.com", "Test", "<b>Test</b>", "some@email.com", AttachmentArray
```

This seems to work but why should the calling be such a hassle? Is there a way make it more simple? Like I create a class, make it `com-visible` and just call it with one easy `Dim` and `set` (or even without the set?)

Sorry if the post contains loads of stupid questions but i'm kinda new to this and especially to DLL's.

Comment: Im thinking if the class were static you may have just been able to call it

Comment: Found it out myself. Can be done using an interface. Will answer my question when possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access COM exposed methods in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574973/unable-to-access-com-exposed-methods-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reading here: http://jumbloid.blogspot.nl/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html I found out that I can easily call my DLL classes using a `public interface`.

So what I added is:

```
public interface ISendMail
    {
        void SendMail(string ToAddress, string Subject, string Body, string FromAddress, ref string[] attachments, string CCAddress = "", string BCCAddress = "");
    }
```

And I added a default constructor in my class:  `public SendOPSMail() { }`

And my class inherits from the created Interface: `public class SendOPSMail : ISendMail`

Now I can easily call the method/class in VBA like this:

```
Dim test As OPS2Mail.SendOPSMail
Set test = New OPS2Mail.SendOPSMail
```